# Proof of equivalence of two definitions of a projective module

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-module

> **Please don't give an alternative proof. I know how to prove this another way, but this argument intrigues me, despite that it (perhaps because it?) makes no sense to me.**

I don't understand this proof in Jonathan Rosenbergs K-theory text. The following was proved in one direction (easily):

The following are equivalent definitions of a projective module:

- $P$ is projective if whenever $A\to P$ is a surjection, there is a right inverse $P\to A$.
- $P$ satisfies the standard diagram completion property (without tikzcd, too much of a bother to render, but yall know it)

They are proving the first implies the second:
[image]

> Please explain the 'we may suppose $\varphi$ is one-to-one'. I am not sure if this is an implication from the replaced diagram, and if it is how it is so. Otherwise I cannot see how it is fair to do this, since it isn't WLOG - and additionally why we stop caring about the diagram immediately afterwards.

Comment: Clearly $\varphi$ is an isomorphism after these replacements. You only have to check that completing the diagram in the replaced case is sufficient to complete the original diagram. This should be obvious for both replacements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is that we have a diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD} & & P \\ & &  @VV{(\varphi,id_P)}V \\ M\times P@>{\psi\times id_P}>> N\times P \\ @V{\pi_M}VV @VV{\pi_N}V\\ M@>>{\psi}> N\end{CD}$$where the lower square commute. Now the existence of a map $\alpha :P\to M$ such that $\psi\alpha=\varphi$ is equivalent to the existence of a map $\alpha':P\to M\times P$ such that $(\psi\times id_P)\alpha'=(\varphi,id_P)$; indeed, given $\alpha$ it suffices to define $\alpha'=(\alpha,id_P)$, and given $\alpha'$ it suffices to define $\alpha=\pi_M\alpha'$.

So in order to prove that $P$ is projective, it is enough to complete the upper part of the diagram above, where now $(\varphi,id_P)$ is one-to-one; so if we know that the diagram completion can always be done under this condition the proof is complete.